# Combining \vfill and \vskip at end of page results in blank line(s)

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing

I want to define an environment, that uses `\vskip` to put some space before and after. Usually it will be used in the normal text, but sometimes I want to push to the bottom of a page with `\vfill`. When the environment is placed at the bottom of a page due to the current text on a page without `\vfill` the `\vskip` afterwards is ignored - but not when using `\vfill`.

Is there a way to get the same behaviour in both cases (ignoring the `\vskip`)?

Even without an environment this happens as the following MWE shows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

test

\vfill % \vskip\baselineskip is added and causes a blank line at the bottom of the page
       % without that \vfill no space (glue) is inserted at the end (see below)

test

\vskip\baselineskip

\end{document}
```

After a little search on this side I found the command `\showoutput` to see what's going on in the document. I tried to find out what is the reason for that difference and achieve what I want ... without any success. Here's the relevant part (I think) of `\showoutput` for that example. The difference is just a single line with or without `\vfill`.

```
...\hbox(6.15+0.11)x345.0, glue set 313.84fil, direction TLT
....\localpar
.....\localinterlinepenalty=0
.....\localbrokenpenalty=0
.....\localleftbox=null
.....\localrightbox=null
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0, direction TLT
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 t
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 e
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 s
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 t
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill % That's the \vfill I guess
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.74
...\hbox(6.15+0.11)x345.0, glue set 313.84fil, direction TLT
....\localpar
.....\localinterlinepenalty=0
.....\localbrokenpenalty=0
.....\localleftbox=null
.....\localrightbox=null
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0, direction TLT
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 t
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 e
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 s
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 t
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 12.0 % That's the \vskip I guess (it disappears without the \vfill)
...\glue -0.11
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
```

By the way, the same happens for `\vspace` or `\addvspace` instead of `\vskip`.

Comment: `\usepackge{showframe}` shows no difference, `\vfill` doesn't expand until the page is done (full), which includes the blank line at the bottpm of the page. You can add a `\pagebreak` so that the blank line is now at the top of the next page. (and will be absorbed)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should define two related environments: `foo` for normal appearance in the text block and `foo*` to move it at the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{foo}{%
  \par\addvspace{\baselineskip}\startfoo
}{%
  \par\addvspace{\baselineskip}%
}
\newenvironment{foo*}{%
  \par\vfill\startfoo
}{%
  \par
}
\newcommand{\startfoo}{\noindent\textbf{Foo.}\ \ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{foo}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{foo}

\lipsum[3][1-5]

\clearpage

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{foo*}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{foo*}

\end{document}
```

The packages I loaded in the preamble are just to produce a smaller picture showing the page margins. I provided a mock definition of the environment.

[image]